# How to use GroupHeader template of a ListView in Xamarin UWP using ListViewRenderer

Tags: uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have the following `HeaderTemplate` defined in `App.xaml`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewGroupHeaderTemplate">
    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="Something" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I use it this way in my `ListViewRenderer`:

```
listView.ItemTemplate = App.Current.Resources["ListViewItemTemplate"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
var gs = new GroupStyle();
gs.HeaderTemplate = App.Current.Resources["ListViewGroupHeaderTemplate"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
listView.GroupStyle.Add(gs);
```

The source of my `ListView` is a `CollectionViewSource`:

```
CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
cvs.IsSourceGrouped = true;

cvs.Source = ((SourceListView)Element).Items;
if (listView.ItemsSource == null)
  listView.ItemsSource = cvs.View;
```

The `ItemTemplate` works well.

This is how my `ListView` looks (the white parts are the group headers):

[image]

What should I set to make the header work?

**UPDATE**:

I modified my source according to the answer (applied grouping to a simple List):

```
    CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
    cvs.IsSourceGrouped = true;
    var items = ((MyListView)Element).Items;
    var itemsAsOC = items as ObservableCollection<GroupListItem>;
    List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>();
    foreach (var item in itemsAsOC)
    {
      list.AddRange(item);
    }
    var group = from item in list group item by item.Value into grp orderby grp.Key select grp;                
    cvs.Source = group;
```

Nothing changed with the headers, so I guess the data source is correct but there is some serious Xamarin UWP bug in template handling:

[image]

***UPDATE 2:***

I tested it *without the Xamarin renderer*, and it shows header items.

[image]

However, when I use the Xamarin renderer, ***the headers are gone***.

[image]

You can [download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8aAkabXOq4vaC1TUmdYb0R1ZVE) and test it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I couldn't find any clear problem in your code, here is how I add `GroupHeader` template to `ListView`.

In App.xaml:

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewGroupHeaderTemplate">
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Key}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewTemplate">
        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding DateTimeProperty}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

Here is my item class and my `SourceListView`:

```cs
public class ListItem
{
    public DateTime DateTimeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SourceListView
{
    public SourceListView()
    {
        Element = from x in Collection group x by x.DateTimeProperty.Year into grp orderby grp.Key select grp;
    }

    public IList<ListItem> Collection { get; set; } = new List<ListItem>()
    {
        new ListItem() {DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Parse("2011-08-01") },
        new ListItem() {DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Parse("2011-08-21") },
        new ListItem() {DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Parse("2012-04-03") },
        new ListItem() {DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Parse("2012-04-01") },
        new ListItem() {DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Parse("2013-05-15") },
        new ListItem() {DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Parse("2013-05-06") },
        new ListItem() {DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Parse("2013-05-01") },
        new ListItem() {DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Parse("2013-06-01") },
        new ListItem() {DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Parse("2013-06-09") },
        new ListItem() {DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Parse("2014-10-02") },
        new ListItem() {DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Parse("2014-10-11") },
        new ListItem() {DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Parse("2015-12-03") },
        new ListItem() {DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Parse("2016-07-01") },
        new ListItem() {DateTimeProperty = DateTime.Parse("2016-07-06") },
    };

    public IEnumerable<object> Element { get; }
}
```

Here is the code of implementation of this grouped `ListView`:

```cs
ListView listView = new ListView();
listView.ItemTemplate = App.Current.Resources["ListViewTemplate"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
var gs = new GroupStyle();
gs.HeaderTemplate = App.Current.Resources["ListViewGroupHeaderTemplate"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
listView.GroupStyle.Add(gs);

CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
cvs.IsSourceGrouped = true;
cvs.Source = new SourceListView().Element;
if (listView.ItemsSource == null)
    listView.ItemsSource = cvs.View;
rootGrid.Children.Add(listView);
```

Here is the rendering image:

[image]

Comment: If I add the following code:˛`listView.HeaderTemplate = App.Current.Resources["ListViewGroupHeaderTemplate"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;`, then the main header appears, so I guess, the group header is set incorrectly. Should I set _a key value_ in my CollectionViewSource?

Comment: @Nestor, if you set `listView.HeaderTemplate = App.Current.Resources["ListViewGroupHeaderTemplate"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;`, then this header is the main header of this ListView, your group should failed to build through the items are in order, but each group's header should be missing..."Should I set a key value in my CollectionViewSource", the key value is for the group title, it used LinQ for grouping, when grouped, they are key-value pair, so I used `Key` for binding in the `ListViewGroupHeaderTemplate`, in `CollectionViewSource`, you just need to add this template.

Comment: I modified my template and the _fix title_ was replaced with `{Binding Key}`, but nothing changed. Also, I guess a fix title should be visible as it doesn't depend on anything while the binding does. I added the `GroupStyle` to my XAML, but the header is still a white rectangle. Very strange and blocks my work.

Comment: I added some information in the initial question. I wasn't emphasizing enough that it is a Xamarin ListViewRenderer that I use.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally after day and a half of struggling with this problem I found the solution. I'll post it here if someone someday face the same problem as me. Actually it is really strange problem and I don't know if it is a bug, unimplemented feature or what...

The solution:

In your UWP custom renderer you need to do this:

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            e.NewElement.GroupHeaderTemplate = new Xamarin.Forms.DataTemplate(() =>
            {
                var label = new Label();

                label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Country");

                return new ViewCell { View = label };
            });
        }
    }
```

Where "Country" is the name of the property from the class representing your Group/Header.